# Drupal BIRT Integration

Tags: 6

I want to integrate BIRT reporting tool with Drupal 6.
Does anyone has an idea on how to do it? BIRT reporting tool basically runs on a Tomcat server.

Answer (score 3):

Searching for "brit drupal" produced:

- [BIRT Open Source Engine integration as a Drupal module for dynamic, BIRT data-driven content pages. Allows multiple BIRT designs to be integrated as its own Drupal content type.](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/deploying-birt-reports/1233-birt-os-drupal-module/)
- [BIRT vs Custom Drupal Module](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=5584.0)
- [BIRT OS Drupal Module](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/deploying-birt-reports/1233-birt-os-drupal-module/)
- [BIRT Module for Drupal 6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hH9A9a3E7k8) (video)

Comment: I try with and got success.